# What declension are θορυβος and κοσμος?

Tags: greek, declension

I'm curious about what declension θορυβος and κοσμος are in Attic Greek. They appear to be second declension (θορυβος, -ου and κοσμος, -ου), but in the Athenaze workbook (which I'm slowly working my way through...), they are listed under first declension nouns.

Is there an error in the book, or are they actually first declension, and if they are, how does that pan out with the other forms (dative, accusative, vocative)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is an error in the workbook. LSJ lists them both as standard masculine second-declension (-os, -ou) nouns.

A good way to find details on individual words is [the Perseus lookup tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph). You can put in any word (even inflected forms!) and it'll tell you what form you have and give its LSJ entry. For example, [if you put in *thórybos*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=qorubos&la=greek), it says it's a nominative masculine singular noun meaning "noise"; click the "LSJ" link to see the full dictionary entry with all sorts of classical examples.

Comment: Okay, thank you!  Awesome tool there, thanks!

Comment: @rotaredom It's a wonderful thing; I'd never have made it through my early Greek classes without it!